# Change current working directory from MySQL client prompt

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to change the current working directory from the MySQL client prompt?

That would allow me to use relative paths for the `tee`, `source`, and another command which I don't recall just now (I just noticed that the post got truncated my copy/pasting, and I had listed a few example commands in the original text file draft -- being new to MySQL, I'm that familiar with the commands off the top of my head).

I found from other apps that changing the working directory is extremely useful in general, e.g., in Vim and Matlab.

Comment: `\! cd /my/new/path`? From [here](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/shell-commands-mysql-command-line-client/).

Comment: Apparently not.  Issuing `tee out2.txt`, some commands, and `notee` results in an output log file in the original working directory rather than `/my/new/path`.  I suspect that a subshell is created for each `\!` command, and the new path only exists until the subshell finishes its command (which is right away after the `cd`).

Comment: What about a shell script with a cron job to do whatever it is you want to do? It might be better if you explained in detail what it is you want to do and why (as a new question, maybe pointing back to this one?). There's more than one way to skin a cat - it's **possible** that your requirement could be met in a different way? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Thanks, Verace.  I just noticed that my posting got truncated, so the reason for changing the working directory is incomplete.  I just want do that as a convenience, which I found to be extremely useful in general when using (say) Matlab and Vim.  Being new to MySQL, I can't recall all the commands I discovered yesterday, but some of the commands that are affected by the working directory are `tee` and `source`.  I will try to recall the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. There is no code in the mysql client executable to change directory.

Comment: OK.  Thanks, danblack.